# Remove duplicates from nested tables in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, nested, duplicates, google-bigquery, standards

We have been starting to work with Google bigQuery nested tables. we are having difficulties to identify duplicates on this table. we tried using Rownumber() function but it means that we need to dive into every record and record. we are talking about a table with more than 10 records in the basic lair of architecture and more than 400 fields

the following code is what we created so far, it gives recognition on duplicates but with as many fields we can write, as I wrote, there are over 400 fields

```
SELECT
    count (*) AS Number_Of_Records --this will let us know how many records there is
FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1, ... , fieldN) AS ranking 
    FROM
        `data.T1`,
        unnest(record1) as record1, --unnesting is a must with nested tables and records
        ....,
        unnest(recordN) as recordN
    )
WHERE
    ranking=1 --duplicats >1
```

we would like to find a shorter way to write this query to find the number of nonduplicates rows, thanks

Comment: Something seems wrong with your data model.  400 array-of-structure columns seems really awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use hash function to identify a record and use this hash to remove duplicates.

So Assuming your JSON data is composed of Strings you can use the following to generate a unique hash code for your records:

```
WITH items AS
  (SELECT ["apples", "bananas", "pears", "grapes"] as list
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ["coffee", "tea", "milk" ] as list
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ["cake", "pie", NULL] as list -- Duplicate record
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ["cake", "pie", NULL] as list)

SELECT distinct FARM_FINGERPRINT(ARRAY_TO_STRING(list, '--')) AS text
FROM items;
```

This results in 3 rows and not 4 as expected (1 rows in duplicate)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! we are saving the hash number for each record on the server side and we can use it in the future, it was good to learn and know. acctually this is a one time query, maybe it was important to say at the beginning. we will create a flat table. and then we find the duplicates by more known methods

Comment: Happy to hear, meanwhile If you found this answer helpful please consider [voting up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235)  it and it's important in SO and will help you grow your reputation in the community

Comment: accepting has been made but there is a notification says no public casting for post of voting up less then 15 votes